# Python 3: Why do I only get one value returned when using 'return'

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, return, pytest

I'm trying to add return statements into my code so that I could use pytest to then check if the output is as expected (at least I think that's how it works, my first time using pytest).

This is the code I have:

```
import itertools


def lists(*usrin):

    # STRINGS IN MULTIPLE LISTS

    temp = set(usrin[0])
    for sub in usrin[1:]:
        res = temp.intersection(sub)
        print("Strings that appear in more than one list: ", ', ' .join(res))
        return res


# UNIQUE STRING COUNT

    nlst = [set(sum(usrin, []))]
    alist = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(nlst))
    print("Number of unique strings: ", len(alist))
    return alist


# TOTAL STRINGS PROCESSED

    count = 0
    for arg in usrin:
        count += (len(arg))
    print("Total number of strings processed: ", count)
    return count


    # CALL WITH INPUT

def main():

    lists(['g', 'gh', 'ghj', 'g'], ['j', 'ju', 'gh', 'gk', 'gn'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My expected output is as follows (which I get if i remove the "return" statements):

```
Strings that appear in more than one list:  gh
Number of unique strings:  7
Total number of strings processed:  9
```

However with the return statements I end up with only:

```
Strings that appear in more than one list:  gh
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way to handle output so that when the program is run it outputs something for the user but can also be tested to make sure that the output is as expected?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: return will cause you to leave the function block. Once a function hits a return it stops. So the first for loop runs, return is hit, function exits.

Answer (score 0):

In your first `for` loop, you return `res` where `res = temp.intersection(sub)`. This causes the function to halt execution and return control to the caller - in this case `lists()` returns and cedes control to the `main()` function from which it was called.

If you just wish to display content in the terminal use `print` (or `print()`) not `return`.

`return` is used when you need the output of one function to be used in another function.

Answer (score 0):

You are inside a function. The first return made all the following statements unreachable.

You should store the strings in a temporary variable, and then return the whole string at the end of the lists function.